# Checking if Ticker is in another list, then adding a new key [RamdaJS]

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to use Ramda to compare 2 lists, find which tickers in the tickersList are also in the portfolioTickers. If one is in the portfolio list as well then add a key `portfolio:true`.

**Example data:**

```
tickers = [
    { ticker: aa },
    { ticker: bb },
    { ticker: cc }
]

portfolio = [
    { ticker: aa }
]
```

**Expected result:**

```
tickers = [
    { ticker: aa, portfolio: true },
    { ticker: bb },
    { ticker: cc }
]
```

**Sounds simple, but stuck here so far:**

```
const checkTicker = _.curry((ticker, portTicker) => {
    if (ticker.ticker === portTicker.ticker) {
        ticker.portfolio = true;
    }
    return ticker;
});

const matched = R.anyPass([checkTicker]);

const setPortfolioFlag = _.curry((portfolioTickers, ticker) => {
    // const matched = R.filter(checkTicker(ticker), portfolioTickers);
    // console.log('matched', matched)
    const each = matched(R.forEach(checkTicker(ticker), portfolioTickers));
    console.log('each', each)

    return each;
});

const inPortfolioCheck = (tickersList) => {
    const portfolioTickers = R.filter(TickersFactory.isTickerInPortfolio, tickersList);
    const tickers = R.map(setPortfolioFlag(portfolioTickers), tickersList);
    console.log('tickers', tickers)
};

const displayTickers = (tickers) => {
    this.tickersList = tickers; 
    const checkedTickers = inPortfolioCheck(this.tickersList);
    console.log('checkedTickers', checkedTickers)
};
```

Right now `each` is always true, and the list that all this logic returns is just a list the same length as my tickerList, but just `true`'.

A problem I keep running into is I feel that I need to run another 2nd `R.map` to do the check, however the result of that returned map is the Portfolio tickers, and not the original list.

---

#### Working code, but with an ugly for loop:

This obviously works because I'm using a for loop, but I'm trying to remove all object oriented code and replace with functional code.

```
const setPortfolioFlag = _.curry((portfolioTickers, ticker) => {
    for (var i=0; i<portfolioTickers.length; i++) {
        if (portfolioTickers[i].ticker === ticker.ticker) {
            ticker.portfolio = true;
        }
    }

    return ticker;
});

const inPortfolioCheck = (tickersList) => {
    const portfolioTickers = R.filter(TickersFactory.isTickerInPortfolio, tickersList);
    return R.map(setPortfolioFlag(portfolioTickers), tickersList);
};

const displayTickers = (tickers) => {
    this.tickersList = inPortfolioCheck(tickers);
    console.log('this.tickersList', this.tickersList)
};
```

---

LoDash version of the forLoop:

```
_.each(portfolio, (port) => {
    if (port.ticker === ticker.ticker) {
        ticker.portfolio = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing you might notice is that the expected resulting `tickers` array is the same "shape" as the input `tickers` array, suggesting that we should be able to make use of `R.map` for the expression. Knowing that, we can then focus on what just has to happen to the individual elements of the array.

So for each ticker object, when found in the `portfolio` array, we would like to attach the `portfolio: true` property.

```
const updateTicker =
  R.when(R.flip(R.contains)(portfolio), R.assoc('portfolio', true))

updateTicker({ ticker: 'aa' })
//=> {"portfolio": true, "ticker": "aa"}

updateTicker({ ticker: 'bb' })
//=> {"ticker": "bb"}
```

Then we can just map over the tickers list to update each ticker.

```
R.map(updateTicker, tickers)
//=> [{"portfolio": true, "ticker": "aa"}, {"ticker": "bb"}, {"ticker": "cc"}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out now, could you explain what's going on in `R.when(R.flip(R.contains)(portfolio), R.assoc('portfolio', true))` Looking up `when`, `flip` and `contains` now.

Comment: This might be slightly more difficult if `portfolio` and `tickers` are oversimplified for demonstration purposes, and don't actually have the same shape.  I was going to try an answer with `any` and `eqProp` in place of `contains` for that case.  But if this one does what you need, I won't bother.

Comment: Well `portfolio` will most of the time always have less or none then `tickers` however this code pertains to a search function. So technically it's possible for a user to search for a list of tickers that are all in his portfolio, like if he added all the top ticker that started with `AA`.

Comment: [`contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains) is simple: `contains(needle, haystack)` returns true if `needle` is in `haystack`.  [`flip`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) reverses parameters of the target function, so `flip(contains)(haystack, needle)` is similar, used above in a curried form as `flip(contains)(haystack)`.  This could also be written `contains(__, haystack)`, depending on your preference.  [`when`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) returns an altered version of the original parameter if the predicate is true, or the parameter itself if it's false.

Comment: The question was about *shape*.  Will the entries of `portfolio` and `tickers` always have only the single `ticker` property, or might they be more complex?

Comment: BOOM! thanks this is what I needed to know `flip(contains)(haystack, needle)` And no these ticker objects have wayyy more stuff in them, but it's the same keys (price, company name etc).

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @scott-christopher is, as always, excellent.  But subsequent comments make me think that it doesn't quite cover your use case.  If the data is more complex, and it's possible that items in the `portfolio` and the `tickers` might have distinct properties, then `contains` won't be strong enough.  So if your data looks more like this:

```
const tickers = [
    { ticker: 'aa', size: 1 },
    { ticker: 'bb', size: 2 },
    { ticker: 'cc', size: 3 },
    { ticker: 'dd', size: 4 }
]

const portfolio = [
    { ticker: 'aa', id: 'abc' },
    { ticker: 'dd', id: 'xyz' }
]
```

Then this version might work better:

```
const updateTicker =
  when(pipe(eqProps('ticker'), any(__, portfolio)), assoc('portfolio', true))
```

This nearly points-free version might be a little obscure.  It's equivalent to this one:

```
const updateTicker =
    when(
        (ticker) => any(eqProps('ticker', ticker), portfolio), 
        assoc('portfolio', true)
    )
```

Also, if the `any(__, portfolio)` notation is unclear, it's equivalent to `flip(any)(portfolio)`.

You can see this on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20tickers%20%3D%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27aa%27%2C%20size%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27bb%27%2C%20size%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27cc%27%2C%20size%3A%203%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27dd%27%2C%20size%3A%204%20%7D%0A]%0A%0Aconst%20portfolio%20%3D%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27aa%27%2C%20id%3A%20%27abc%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27dd%27%2C%20id%3A%20%27xyz%27%20%7D%0A]%0A%0A%2F%2Fconst%20updateTicker%20%3D%0A%2F%2F%20%20when%28ticker%20%3D%3E%20any%28eqProps%28%27ticker%27%2C%20ticker%29%2C%20portfolio%29%2C%20assoc%28%27portfolio%27%2C%20true%29%29%0A%0A%2F%2Fconst%20updateTicker%20%3D%0A%2F%2F%20%20when%28pipe%28eqProps%28%27ticker%27%29%2C%20flip%28any%29%28portfolio%29%29%2C%20assoc%28%27portfolio%27%2C%20true%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20updateTicker%20%3D%0A%20%20when%28pipe%28eqProps%28%27ticker%27%29%2C%20any%28__%2C%20portfolio%29%29%2C%20assoc%28%27portfolio%27%2C%20true%29%29%0A%0AupdateTicker%28%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27aa%27%2C%20size%3A%201%20%7D%29%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7B%22portfolio%22%3A%20true%2C%20siae%3A%201%2C%20%22ticker%22%3A%20%22aa%22%7D%0A%0AupdateTicker%28%7B%20ticker%3A%20%27bb%27%2C%20size%3A%202%20%7D%29%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Bsize%3A%202%2C%20%22ticker%22%3A%20%22bb%22%7D%0A%0AR.map%28updateTicker%2C%20tickers%29)**.

Comment: Your original worked even with ticker objects that have over a dozen keys. Trying to wrap my head around this: `R.when(R.pipe(R.eqProps('ticker'), R.any(R.__, favorites))` Don't get what the `pipe` or `__` does, even after reading the docs a couple times lol. What I get is if the `prop` ticker of ticker matches `any` in favorites, then `assoc` the new key `favorites` with the value of true and return the ticker.

Comment: The two versions should work exactly the same.  The second is an expansion of the first.  `pipe` simply hooks several functions together in a pipeline, sending the result of one into the next.  `__` is just a way to partially apply the values of a function out of order.  If you supply the placeholder for the first parameter and an actual second parameter, then you get back a new function looking for that first one (and third, fourth...)